# google map displays on Opera Mobile but not on Google default mobile browser

Tags: android, mobile, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know of any reason why a google map coded in HTML5 would show up in Opera Mobile but not Google mobile default browser?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of Web mobile, Google default browser sends a mobile userAgent, so webpages show a specific ui for mobile.

Opera Mobile, can be configured so send desktop user agents, this let you see the web pages as you see them on a desktop

Comment: I see, is it possible to change this?

Comment: From your page, or mobile device?

Comment: yep, found out its not that. Tried both

Comment: Install Chrome in your android device, browse the page you want to test, and put "Request desktop site" in options

Comment: yep done that but didnt work. Maybe theres a debug program for chrome out there....